# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject defaults nullable int to 0

Tags: c#, json

Hello I have the following code, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject default the missing int to 0 even tho it's nullable. How can I have null for age?

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get;  set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Age should be between 0 and 100")]
    public int? Age { get;  set; }
}
public class HelloWorld
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"name\":\"mmmm\"}";
        Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World " + person.Age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, to create a `Person` instance, its constructor has to be used, obviously. Please take a look at the Person constructor.

Comment: As MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace said, either make the `age` parameter of the constructor nullable or add a parameterless constructor to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have a constructor that gets `age` as `int` and not `int?`. You should change it as follows:

```
public Person(string name, int? age)
{
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
}
```

Comment: Another option, in case the purpose of this constructor was to always provide a value for the `Age` property, would be to add a parameterless constructor to the class.